# subprocess.Popen().communicate() does not send data to stdin

Tags: python, shell, subprocess

When I execute code below. Easyrsa script does not pass data from my script. It displays its own input dialog instead. What do I do wrong?

```
def create_serverkey(password, ca_password, server_filename='vpn_server'):
    cmd = [f'{EASYRSA}/./easyrsa', 'build-server-full', server_filename]
    input_msg = f'{password}\n{password}\n{ca_password}\n'
    with subprocess.Popen(cmd, 
                          stdin=subprocess.PIPE,
                          stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                          stderr=subprocess.PIPE,
                          encoding='utf8', text=True) as proc_serverkey:

        stdout, stderr = proc_serverkey.communicate(input=input_msg)
        proc_serverkey.wait()
```

[image: Example. How it looks in a terminal.]

Comment: It must be using `/dev/tty` instead of `stdin` and `stdout`. Use `pexpect` to control an interactive process.

Comment: One can also use `unbuffer` from the `expect` distribution to wrap a program and  make content that's on stdin look like it's coming from a TTY. (`cmd = ['unbuffer', f'{EASYRSA}/bin/easyrsa', ...]`)

Comment: BTW, this (prompting for passwords direct from the TTY instead of via stdin) is often deliberately done by tools handling sensitive credentials where the author of that tool deliberately depends to make it difficult to script in a way that would require passing security-sensitive data around through (oft-insecure) scripts.

Comment: ...that said, easyrsa is a very thin wrapper; if you find it getting in your way much, I would strongly consider going direct to OpenSSL or another underlying implementation (and I say this as someone who was an active part of the OpenVPN support community back when easy-rsa was being created as a tool for OpenVPN's users). There are also newer/arguably-better still-thin wrappers that compete with it and were written with automation as a first-class use case; I see a lot of modern projects choosing cloudflare's cfssl where easy-rsa would have been used in the past.

Comment: Another thing: Through appropriate configuration of `openssl.cnf`, OpenSSL can be told to get passwords and other data from the environment rather than prompting from either stdin _or_ the TTY. So if this prompt is coming from OpenSSL itself (which I don't recall offhand -- it's been a lot of years since I did anything with the easy-rsa codebase), you can avoid it altogether (and choose a safer/saner/built-for-programmatic-use method to pass the data instead) via a config file change.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy thank you a lot. You gave me full and complete information that i use for better understanding what i have to learn and use. I appreciate you taking the time to share your experience.

Comment: I am working on the script that will build, deploy openvpn server and also generate clients' .ovpn files. It is a training project for my portfolio.